# AsyncTask onProgressUpdate is called repeatedly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**The Problem**

AsyncTask onProgressUpdate is called multiple times continuously and will not stop. onProgressUpdate gets called +1000 times a second continuously.

- publishProgress() is called 3 times. (as expected)
- onPostExecute is executed, but onProgressUpdate carries on being called.
- I have another AsynTask in the app that is applied in a similar fashion, and it works just fine.

**The Feature**

I have a grid of items which are gone through until it stops at a selected item. The selection is shown by changing the background of the RelativeLayout.

**Simplified Code**

```
public class test extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    ...
    private class Async_wordletNewCharacter extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        RelativeLayout gridItem;
        RelativeLayout itemSel;
        Drawable goldDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sh_circle_gold);

        public Async_wordletNewCharacter(String param) {super();}

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
                for (int i = 0; i < positionList.size(); i++) {
                    int position = positionList.get(i);
                    gridItem = (RelativeLayout) gridView.getChildAt(position);
                    itemSel = (RelativeLayout) gridItem.findViewById(R.id.item_selector);
                    publishProgress(0);      // Circle the selected item
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.publishProgress(values);
            itemSel.setBackground(goldDrawable);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean a) {
            Log.d(LOG, "async_wait : onPostExecute");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super.publishProgress(values);` is the culprit. Obviously, you meant `super.onProgressUpdate(values);` didn't you?

Comment: Thank you so much Rajesh! Man, what a silly mistake haha